# The function $\Delta X: X → X \times X$ defined $\Delta X (x) = (x, x)$ is sometimes called the diagonal. It is always injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Can someone please tell me if this is a valid solution to this problem?

The function $\Delta X: X → X \times X$ defined $\Delta X (x) = (x, x)$ is sometimes called the diagonal. It is always injective?

Solution - The function is not always injective as two different sets or two different domains with the same elements but different orders will have the same cartesian product and therefore will have the same codomain.

Let $X = \{1,2\}$

Let $Y = \{2,1\}$

$X \neq Y$ as $\{1,2\} \neq \{2,1\}$

$\Delta X: \{1,2\} \rightarrow {1,2} \times \{1,2\} = \{\{1,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,1\}, \{2,2\}\}$

$\Delta Y: \{2,1\} \rightarrow \{2,1\} × \{2,1\} = \{\{2,2\}, \{2,1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,1\}\}$

The codomain of the cartesian product of both sets is equivalent to each other therefore it can be said that the function $\Delta X: X \rightarrow X \times X$ is not always injective.

Comment: Why is $X\neq Y$? Which element of $X$ is not an element of $Y$? Which element of $Y$ is not an element of $X$?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by "≠" is that both sets are not equal to each other. As the order of elements within the set is different.

Comment: Sets don't care about order $\{1,2\}=\{2,1\}$

Comment: @Emaan: I understand you meant that by $\neq$ the sets are not equal to one another. My point is that for two sets $X$ and $Y$ to *not be equal*, there should be something in one that is not in the other. In other words, either $X$ must have an element that is not in $Y$ or $Y$ must have an element which is not in $X$. So, since you claim that the two sets are not equal, I am asking you to tell me what element is witnessing that.

Comment: "$\Delta X$ is injective" means:  If $x \ne y$ then $(x,x) \ne (y,y)$.  It is not about different sets $X$.

Comment: To show a function is injective, I would suggest the following: Assume Δ(x) = Δ(y), and show that x = y. So, if we assume (x,x) = (y,y) what can we say about x and y? Note: I am recommending using the contrapositive formulation of the definition @GEdgar is pointed out. As others have mentioned, {2,1} = {1,2} are actually the same set, because sets are defined as being equal when they have the same elements.

Comment: In addition to the problem @AsafKaragila pointed out, you are mixing up the function $\Delta X: X\to X\times X$ which is the diagonal function on elements of a fixed set, with a sort of higher order function mapping a set $X$ to the set of elements on its diagonal, whose domain and codomain would be the class of all sets.

You have no need to talk about multiple sets in order to answer your question.  Consider $X$ some *fixed* set, and ask yourself if two elements of $X$ can map to the same element on the diagonal.

Comment: Some readers may find it useful to note that the diagonal map is injective because it has a left inverse, namely either projection. This approach works in any category where $X\times X$ exists; it shows that the diagonal is monic.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is not correct.  By your reasoning that $\{1,2\} \not= \{2,1\}$, it would also be the case that $\{\{1,1\},\{1,2\},\{2,1\},\{2,2\}\} \not= \{\{2,2\},\{2,1\},\{1,2\},\{1,1\}\}$ since the elements aren't in the same order.  To show that $\Delta X$ is injective, let $(x,x),(y,y) \space \epsilon \space X \times X $ such that $(x,x) = (y,y)$.  Then necessarily $x=y$, which means that no two different points of $X$ map to the same point in $X \times X$.